# Serialize the order of a sortable list populated by sqlalchemy database in Flask website

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask, sqlalchemy

I am creating a website which allows the admin to write in menu items, re-arrange them by dragging and dropping them on an admin page, serialize them, and have them post on the main page that customers land on. I am quite new to some aspects of this so bear with me as I try to explain. thanks in advance.

a big issue in index.html is that I do not know jquery and bridging it to sqlalchemy is beyond my understanding at this point. the jquery I have below is something I "appropriated" from another stackoverflow question, one that did not answer my question completely. I think the AJAX most likely need to be changed

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>

        <!-- sortable script -->
        <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
                update: function(event, ui) {
                    var postData = $(this).sortable('serialize');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        url: '/post'
                    });
                }
            });
        });


        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Admin Page</h1>

            <!-- FORM (I have left this out for clarity) -->


            <!-- MENU ITEMS -->

            <div class="container menu">
                <ul id="sortable">
                    {% for item in items %}
                    <li class="nobull" id="item_{{ item.id }}">
                        <div class="menu_item">
                            {% if item.head == True %}

                                <div class="menu_heading">
                                    {{ item.name }}

                                </div>

                            {% else %}

                                <div class="menu_item_name">
                                    {{ item.name }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="menu_item_description">
                                    {{ item.description }}
                                </div>

                            {% endif %}

                            <a href="{{ url_for('delete_item', item_id=item.id) }}">Delete</a>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>

                <a href="{{ url_for('post') }}" class="save">Save & Post</a>
            </div>


        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

The main point of focus in the routes file is post() and how to serialize the re-ordered menu-items

routes.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for
from siamsite.forms import NewItem
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

class MenuItem(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    # rank = db.Column(db.Integer)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=False, nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    head = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    spice = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    vegetarian = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"MenuItems('{self.name}', '{self.description}')"

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = NewItem()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_item = MenuItem(name=form.name.data,
                            description=form.description.data,
                            head=form.head.data
                            )
        db.session.add(new_item)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('You successfully added a new menu item!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    items = MenuItem.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, items=items, title='Siam Street Food')


@app.route("/post", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post():

    #serialize the re-ordered list here by changing the item MenuItem id
    #in sqlalchemy to make it match the order of the re-ordered list        

    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: This question comes across as broad. My advice would be not to overwrite `MenuItem.id` as it is the primary key, and add a `sortorder` column. Your post from the front end could then be as simple as a list of `{id: sortorder}` key, value pairs. E.g. if menu item 1 was to sit in position 2, the jquery post could send something like: `{1: 2}`.

Comment: @SuperShoot Thank you for your input. I also thought of doing it this way as well, you can see in the routes.py when I defined the db, I added a "rank" column (mimicking your "sortorder"). Could you please help me figure out how to create the list of value pairs... should I be doing that in JS, if so, how could I go about doing that... I am sorry to ask this way, I am quite new to all this, just a couple months in and I am at a snag!

Comment: `$( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).attr('id') );
});` Maybe something like that except instead of writing to console, push to an object. Example only slightly modified from [here](https://api.jquery.com/each/).